# How to Increase Timer speed with one button

Tags: java

I have a timer and I'm adding a JButton which increases the speed of the Timer 1x the first time clicked then 4x if the button is clicked again. So far what I have is increasing the Timer 1x then the button switches Icons to the 4x Icon but from there I do not know how to increase the the speed 4x.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent theEvent) {
        if (myTimer.isRunning()) { // Make sure timer is running.
            myRace.advance(Utilities.MILLIS_PER_SEC);//Increases timer speed by 1000 milliseconds
            setIcon("./images/ic_four_times.png");//After button is pressed increasing speed change icon to 4x icon
            if(myTimer.isRunning()) { // Attempt to increase speed 4x but logic is flawed
                myRace.advance(Utilities.MILLIS_PER_SEC * 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post does not have nearly enough information.

What exactly does the `myRace.advance()` method do? In what way is it related to the Swing Timer (**myTimer**) being used?

The Timer speed is related to the **delay** in milliseconds set upon the Timer. The lower the milliseconds the faster the Timer fires its' related **Action Performed** event therefore `MILLIS_PER_SEC * 4` would in fact slow down the Timer if the `myRace.advance()` method is indeed changing the Timer's delay rate since this would ultimately supply a Delay setting of 4000 (4 seconds) to the Timer.

By now you may have guessed, to change the `myTimer` Timer's speed you need to set a new **Delay** rate (in milliseconds) for that Timer:

```
myTimer.setDelay(500);
```

If the Timer's initial delay was set to 1000 milliseconds (1 second or Utilities.MILLIS_PER_SEC) and the Timer is running, when you apply the above new setting to that Timer it will immediately fire its' **Action Performed** event twice as fast (every half second). If you want the Timer to fire its' **Action Performed** event 4 times faster than 1 second then your calculation needs to use division (not multiplication) to accomplish it, well...not unless you want to do your multiplication with **0.25** instead of **4** which will provide the same result (1000 / 4 = 1000 * 0.25):

```
myTimer.setDelay(Utilities.MILLIS_PER_SEC / 4);
```

This of course would work out to be a setting of **250** milliseconds, which is considerably faster. If there is going to be any game component ***advancing*** then it should always advance at the same setting and never change (unless under specific game circumstances), let the firing speed of the Timer's **Action Performed** event determine the speed of that particular game component. This then goes to say that any game component that requires ***advancing*** should perhaps be done through the Timer's **Action Performed** event.

If there are other game components that require a different speed rate then each should perhaps have its own Timer. It is also wise to have your Timer(s) in individual Threads or utilize an **ExecutorService** mechanism. This of course depends upon specific needs for your particular application.

A speed setting of **1x** seems more like a default. With that in mind perhaps you example code should be something more like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Start the Timer if it's not running.
    if (!myTimer.isRunning()) {
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("./images/ic_four_times.png"));
        jButton1.setName("4x");
        jButton1.setText("4x Speed");
        speed = 1000;                   // Default (1x)
        myTimer.setDelay(speed);        // Set the Timer delay rate to the default
        myTimer.start();                // Start the Timer!
    }
    // Toggle Timer to 1x speed...
    else if (myTimer.isRunning() && jButton1.getName().equals("1x")) {
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("./images/ic_four_times.png"));
        jButton1.setName("4x");
        jButton1.setText("4x Speed");
        speed = 1000;                   // Default (1x)
        myTimer.setDelay(speed);        // Set the Timer delay rate to 1x
    }
    // Toggle Timer to 4x speed...
    else {
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("./images/ic_one_times.png"));
        jButton1.setName("1x");
        jButton1.setText("1x Speed");
        speed = 1000 / 4;               // Notice the division
        myTimer.setDelay(speed);        // Set the Timer delay rate to 4x
    }
}
```

Of course your button object name will be different but I'm sure you get the idea. With this concept when the application first starts the Button would have a caption of **Start**. To start the ball rolling (so to speak) and fire up the Timer you would click on this start button:

- Once selected and because the Timer is not running the `4x` Icon is
  applied to the JButton, the JButton's **Name** property is changed to
  `4x`, the JButton's caption is set to `4x Speed`, the class member
  variable **speed** is set to hold a default of 1000 milliseconds (1
  second), this speed value is then set as the Timer's delay rate, and
  finally the Timer (myTimer) is started.
- If the JButton is selected again and the Timer is in fact running
  then the JButton's Icon is changed to the `1x` icon, the JButton's
  **Name** property is set to `1x`, the JButton's caption is changed to `1x Speed`, the class member variable **speed** is set to hold a
  value of 1000 / 4 milliseconds (1/4 second), this speed value is then
  set as the Timer's delay rate and the Timer changes speed.
- If the JButton is selected yet again (for the third time) and the
  Timer is in fact running then the JButton's Icon is changed to the
  `4x` icon, the JButton's **Name** property is set to `4x`, the
  JButton's caption is changed to `4x Speed`, the class member variable
  **speed** is set to hold the default value of 1000 milliseconds (1 second), this speed value is then set as the Timer's delay rate and
  the Timer changes speed.
- This JButton will now continuously toggle the Timer between 1x and 4x
  speeds every time it is selected. Another button or means can be used
  to stop the Timer (`myTimer.stop();`) when or if required.

You may or my not like this concept but I think you may be able to get something from it.

On another note, look at your example code. Can you see how you have nested your **IF** statements? Because the Timer is running both calls from each **IF** blocks to the **myRace.advance()** method will be carried out upon each hit of the JButton. That means that the **myRace.advance()** is called twice with each selection and of course the last one called is the `myRace.advance(Utilities.MILLIS_PER_SEC * 4);`. Would be interesting to know exactly what this method does ;) but I'm sure it's provinding some unexpected results.

And finally...Perhaps my Java8+ is already too old but I'm not aware that you can set a JButton's icon using the **setIcon()** method by supplying it with a string path:

```
setIcon("./images/ic_four_times.png");
```

This shouldn't compile! The **setIcon()** method requires a **Icon** or a **ImageIcon** type object.